# Should we remove Code Golf questions from on-topic on FAQ

Tags: discussion, status-completed

See more about this discussion on Mark Trapp's [comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73332/have-code-golf-questions-been-implicitly-disallowed-on-stackoverflow-now-that-mi/73372#73372) and [question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67780/why-is-code-golf-now-the-domain-of-programmers-se).

So, I'm directly asking for permission to drop it.

Comment: Could you please include a definition for Code Golf, just so we are sure we're actually talking about the same thing?

Comment: @Macneil, I'm not sure what you mean by Code Golf, but "Code Gold" means about the same thing in many places: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_golf

Answer (score 9):

Yes, please do.  Code golf is too code specific for PSE and belongs on SO, IMO.

Comment: There's a dedicated site for it. See http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3):

Most of my response is in [the question I posed on Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67780/why-is-code-golf-now-the-domain-of-programmers-se), but it's so completely out of place here. Our de-facto elevator pitch involves saying Programmers.SE is for all those things *about* programming that aren't *actually* programming, and Code Golf *is* programming (albeit *fun* programming).

Comment: @Michael: right, is there something in my response that goes against that? Because that'd be unintentional.

Comment: Sorry - didn't read your other post and misunderstood you.