# Can we remove "programming puzzles" from appropriate questions to ask on Programmers?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, on-topic-definition

There is [this question from December 2010](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/831/should-we-remove-code-golf-questions-from-on-topic-on-faq), with 10 upvotes for removing code golf from being on-topic here. There are also a total of 17 upvotes on posts advocating a separate puzzles/golf sits in [this question, also from 2010](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/38/where-do-code-golf-code-challenge-questions-belong). The "code golf" Stack Exchange is officially called ["Programming Puzzles and Code Golf"](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/), making it on topic there.

I haven't seen very many puzzle/golf questions here, but I was reading the FAQ and noticed that this still exists. It's probably a hold over from before the other site was opened.

> What kind of questions can I ask here?
>
> Programmers - Stack Exchange is for expert programmers who are interested in conceptual questions on software development.
>
> This can include topics such as:
>
> Software engineering
>
> Developer testing
>
> Algorithm and data structure concepts
>
> Design patterns
>
> Architecture
>
> Development methodologies
>
> Quality assurance
>
> Software law
>
> **Programming puzzles**
>
> Freelancing and business concerns

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've removed the line about programming puzzles.

Unfortunately I can't edit section that mentions where questions might be on topic to add Code Golf in there. Though as it's still in beta it might not be allowed anyway.

Comment: We could add it to our custom "things that are off-topic section"?

Comment: I don't see why not.

Comment: I would be a little leery about adding it to off-topic, unless it becomes a problem.  I don't think people should be encouraged to attempt to label things as "programming puzzles" when a question might say something about puzzles, but at the core may be a good programmers question (about interviews, learning/training, etc.). It might be difficult to explain in the FAQ that it's the puzzles *themselves* that are off topic.

Comment: @Renesis Good point.

Comment: @Renesis @Anna Lear That is a good point. I believe software development position interview-related questions would be on topic, and some might involve puzzles. However, I would think the line would be drawn where a "solve this puzzle" question would be off-topic and a "is this puzzle a valid assessment of my abilities" would be on-topic.